# Edittext focus on start and prevent pushing layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I'd like to focus my `EditText` view to focus on activity startup, so I have

```
<activity
    android:name=".TestViewActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

This is a second activity that is started on a `Button` click. The `EditText` will not receive focus on startup without `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible` so that's why I have that. My problem is that it is receiving focus but it is also pushing up the above `TextView` even with `adjustPan`. This is my whole xml file for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/typeView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/wordsView"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd like to be able to get focus and prevent the keyboard from pushing the `TextView` up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" from Manifest.

Within your activity's onCreate() add the below code,

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.typeView);
myEditText.requestFocus(); //Gets focus on Edit text.
```

Comment: Or you can request the focus in your layout using `<requestFocus />` like this:
 `<EditText
    ...>
    <requestFocus />
   </EditText>`